# How to grep all words starting with digit?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am wondering how to grep all words starting with digit. So far, I have made this:

```
egrep "^[[:digit:]]" tst
```

But it prints me just a lines starting with digit.

Thanks in advance with help.

Comment: If you don't mind printing the whole line, you can do `\b[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: If I do?Is there any other solution?

Comment: What characters are allowed in a "word"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `grep` supports Perl Compatible RegExp (`-P`), you can do:

```
grep -Po '(?<=^|\s)\d[^\s]*(?=\s|$)' file.txt
```

- Assuming by `word` you meant characters separated by whitespaces only
- `?<=^|\s)` is the zero width positive look behind pattern ensuring our desired word is preceded by either the start of the line or a whitespace
- `\d[^\s]*` is our desired match, word starting with a digit
- `(?=\s|$)` is the zero width positive lookahead pattern ensuring our desired match is followed by a whitespace or end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print a list of the words beginning with a digit, one per line, you can do this:

```
tr -cs '[:digit:][:alpha:]' '\n' | grep '^[:digit:]'
```

The `tr` command lists all of the strings of alpha-numeric characters, one per line.  Then grep only needs to look at digits at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
echo "foo bar 11baz q3ux
one, 2two? three!" | grep -o '\<[[:digit:]][^[:blank:]]*\>'
```

```
11baz
2two
```

This uses `\<` and `\>` for start- and end-of-word markers respectively.